# How do I calculate an array of differences?

Tags: swift

Given an array: `[1,3,6,8]`

How would I create the array `[1,2,3,2]` ? (i.e. `[1, 3-1, 6-3, 8-6]`)

I wrote some stupidly complex code that just crashes. I want to use the `map`, or `reduce` functions to make the array compute expression really nice and short.

Help ? I know this is simple but I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can use `map` to do this fairly easily. You just have to keep track of the item before the current one.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
// your array
let arr = [1, 3, 6, 8]

// a variable to keep track of the previous item
var previousItem = 0
let arrOfDifferences:[Int] = arr.map {item in // the current item
    defer {previousItem = item} // set the previous item to the current one, after the return happens
    return item-previousItem // return the difference
}

print(arrOfDifferences) // [1, 2, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the **very** quick answer! I love Stack sometimes :) It works splendidly.

Comment: Happy to help! I hope my comments clearly explain what's going on in the code :)

Comment: yeah I figured it out :)

Answer (score 7):

You can "zip" the array with a shift of itself and map the result
to the differences:

```
let numbers = [1,3,6,8]
let diffs = numbers.prefix(1) + zip(numbers, numbers.dropFirst()).map { $1 - $0 }
print(diffs) // [1, 2, 3, 2]
```

Explanation:

- `numbers.prefix(1)` returns a sequence with the initial array
  element.
- `numbers.dropFirst()` is a subsequence of all elements but the first,
  in this case `3, 6, 8`.
- `zip(...)` creates a sequence of pairs, stopping when the shorter
  input sequence is exhausted, in this case `(1, 3), (3, 6), (6, 8)`.
- `map { $1 - $0 }` maps this sequence of pairs to an array of the
  element-wise differences, in this case `2, 6, 3`.

Comment: Here I thought I was zipping all originally on my own, only to realize my browser failed to update the thread until I posted my >6 minute-to-write answer :0)! Much nicer with the `dropFirst` and implicit discarding of trailing elements of sequences of non-matching lengths than the mad explicit slicing in my (deleted) answer, nice!

Comment: Wow... really took some time to understand your answer. It's super clean though, just hard to understand at first... I am still gonna keep originaluser2 's answer because it is really much simpler to understand and much more intuitive. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `reduce`:

```
[1,3,6,8].reduce(([], 0)) {
    ($0.0 + [$1 - $0.1], $1)
}.0 // [1,2,3,2]
```

**Edit**: here's another solution with `reduce` that probably will perform better:

```
var differences = [Int]()
[1,3,6,8].reduce(0) {
    differences.append($1 - $0)
    return $1
}
// differences is now [1,2,3,2]
```

Comment: OK, I'm definitely impressed!

Comment: I believe it's worth mentioning that using a growing array as a collector in a reduce operation (or in this case, a tuple where the 1st elem. is an array) can yield quite an overhead, which might become non-negligible once you reach arrays of sizes ~100 elements of more (depending of course on hardware, but as a rule of thumb). From the technical/functional aspect of Swift, the solution above is interesting and has its merit, but w.r.t. performance, one should take care when applying solutions as this one in practice (even with Knuth:s reminder regarding premature optimiz. taken into account:)

Comment: @dfri You're absolutely right, my initial solution probably runs in O(n^2). I've added a second way to do it with `reduce` that will hopefully be quicker :)

Comment: @dfri I also found the time to do a quick benchmark, but got different results. While Tim's first method is slower (around 15x), his second method is just as quick as the others. It appears Swift is able to optimise repeated calls to `.append`, and [after looking at the docs](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Array/), I found that "*Array, ContiguousArray, and ArraySlice share an exponential growth strategy that makes append a constant time operation when amortized over many invocations.*" I also tried to improve the performance further by using `.reserveCapacity`, but this had v. little effect

Comment: @originaluser2 That's what I also found in earlier benchmarks with `append`, but I didn't find the time to do it yesterday for this case. Thanks!

Comment: @dfri Oh, I've made that mistake before. Playgrounds definitely don't have the fancy optimisations normal projects have. Thanks for your involvement :)