# Coolest way combining items in Swift 3

Tags: swift

Say... I have an array `[ 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9]`.  I like to make another array from it. like `["1-2", "2-4", "4-5", "5-6", "6-9"]` which is based on one previous item and the other item followed by.  What would be the coolest way to achieve this in Swift 3?  Yes, I know how to do this old fashion way.  But I am wondering, if there is a cool or simple way to do this by using such as `map`, `reduce` or others.

Thanks,

Comment: Similar: [How do I calculate an array of differences?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634032/how-do-i-calculate-an-array-of-differences).

Comment: Uprooted @vacawama's answer. That said, why does it matter if it's "cool" at the expense of being something understandable? At the very least, this needs an inline comment about what is trying to be achieved.... **Swifty** is not necessarily equivalent to **cool**.

Comment: Yah, right... by mentioning cool to just differentiate from classical fashion way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zip` and `map` along with `dropLast` and `dropFirst` to generate the result:

```
let arr = [ 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9]

let result = zip(arr.dropLast(), arr.dropFirst()).map { "\($0)-\($1)" }
print(result)
```

Output:

> ```
> ["1-2", "2-4", "4-5", "5-6", "6-9"]
> ```

`zip` works by creating a sequence of tuple pairs from the two sequences.  `map` then takes these pairs and combines them using `String` interpolation.

---

As @MartinR pointed out, since `zip` works with different length sequences, you can skip the `dropLast()`:

```
let result = zip(arr, arr.dropFirst()).map { "\($0)-\($1)" }
```

From the documentation seen when you <kbd>option</kbd>-click on `zip`:

> If the two sequences passed to zip(*:*:) are different lengths, the
>   resulting sequence is the same length as the shorter sequence.

Comment: It works even without the `dropLast()`

Comment: Thanks, that's actually simple and neat.